# Discrete solution for alternate zero (low) and one (high) at output?

Tags: transistors, capacitor

I am trying to figure out a discrete solution for alternate low and high at the output for varying input. Consider the discrete solution as a block.

Input to the system consist of a push-button. Normally input to the system will be high. When pressed the push-button, input to the system will be low. Each time prasing the push button(that is input goes to low), output should change the state from previous state( that is low (0) to high (1) or high (1) to low (0)).

Any lead to the solution will be helpful.

Comment: This is called a *t flip-flop*. Google image search should give you a solution from there.

Comment: Thanks for update. I was more inclined solution with discretes. Not chip based.

Comment: Build a flipflop from discrete parts or use its design to inspire what you need.